# Последовательные логические операции с элементами varargs

Tags: java, логические-выражения, varargs

Застрял на логических операциях в массиве.
Необходимо: создать метод, который принимал бы на вход переменную String c двумя значениями OR или AND, а также varargs с булевыми значениями:  static boolean getResult(String operand, boolean... args).
Данный метод должен осуществить логическую операцию (указанную в переменной String) над каждым элементом varargs аргумента и вернуть результат вычисления.
К сожалению, аналогия с суммой элементов массива(где изначально объявляется переменная, скажем int sum=0, а потом к ней прибавляются все элементы массива не подходит, так как первоначальное булево значение может быть разным). Я написал код

```java
static boolean getResult(String operand, boolean...args) {
        
    boolean result= false;
    
    switch (operand) {
        case ("OR"):
            for (int i=0; i< args.length-1; i++) {
                for (int j = i+1; j < args.length; j++) {
                     result = args[i] || args[j];
                     break;
                }
            }
        case("AND"):
            for (int i=0; i< args.length-1; i++) {
                for (int j = i+1; j < args.length; j++) {
                    result = args[i] && args[j];
                }
            }
            break;
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

Но похоже, что он не работает корректно.
Основная проблема: как последовательно  провести логические операции И (ИЛИ) с элементами массива по порядку.
Заранее благодарен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь не нужны вложенные циклы, достаточно пройтись по массиву один раз, а вот первоначальное значение будет определяться по типу операции: для AND таким значением будет `true`, для OR - `false`:

```java
static boolean getResult(String operand, boolean...args) {
    boolean result = false;
    switch (operand) {
        case "OR":
            for (int i = 0; !result && i < args.length; i++) {
                result |= args[i];
            }
            break;
        case "AND":
            result = true;
            for (int i = 0; result && i < args.length; i++) {
                result &= args[i];
            }
            break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

---

Также можно применить Stream API: проитерировать массив `args` при помощи потока индексов, полученных при помощи `IntStream::range`, и используя методы `allMatch` / `anyMatch` для AND / OR соответственно для вычисления результата; для проверки типа операции можно применить switch expression:

```java
static boolean getResult(String operand, boolean...args) {
    return switch(operand) {
        case "AND" -> IntStream.range(0, args.length).allMatch(i -> args[i]);
        case "OR"  -> IntStream.range(0, args.length).anyMatch(i -> args[i]);
        default    -> false;
    };
}
```

---

Тесты (для любой реализации):

```java
System.out.println(getResult("AND", true, true, true));   // -> true
System.out.println(getResult("AND", true, false, true));  // -> false

System.out.println(getResult("OR", false, true, false));  // -> true
System.out.println(getResult("OR", false, false, false)); // -> false
```

Comment: благодарю вас за помощь. Не могли бы вы пояснить почему в OR первоначально будет false а в AND -true,поскольку  это не совсем ясно

Comment: AND аналог произведения, поэтому начальное значение следует проинициализировать логической единицей `true`, и как только будет обнаружен `false` результат станет также `false`.  Соответственно, OR аналог суммы, для вычисления аккумулятор инициализируется логическим нулём `false`

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо!